# Need FTP Proxy for RHEL as RPM

Tags: linux, proxy, ftp, redhat

I need to set up an FTP Proxy on a Red Hat Enterprise Linux server. I have the following requirements:

1. Must run under RHEL 3, 4 & 5
2. Must be available as an RPM
3. Must be under active development

I've already looked into Frox but there is no RHEL RPM that I can find - and ftpproxy which does not seem to have been updated since 2004.

Is there another option out there that meets all my needs?

UPDATE:
Turns out I had another requirement I didn't even know had to be specified.

The proxy must be able to support authentication. Squid is useless because it is only an anonymous FTP proxy. TBH, I find it disingenuous to even call something so limited an FTP proxy!

The proxy has to allow users to log in to external web hosting.

Comment: Is it really that important how recently it's been updated? It's entirely possible that there have been no major issues since then. INN2, for example, hasn't been updated in a similar amount of time, but is perfectly stable.

Comment: Since this proxy server will be exposed to the world I'm particularly sensitive about security on it. If a project isn't active then how can we rely on them dealing with security issues promptly - or indeed at all!?

Answer (score 1):

Could you explain the logic behind your requirements? Finding a binary for a single version or even compiling your own will help you reach your goal faster than finding a binary package that has binary compatibility with RHEL 3. That version hasn't even been updated by **Redhat** in two years!

Comment: The server the ftp proxy has to go on is RHEL 3 - and it is not being changed - I wanted it to go on a newer server but it was not to be. So I'm stuck with RHEL 3.

As for why it has to be a binary RPM - we have a policy, nothing goes on a server that's not a binary RPM.

So in short - reality combined with policy is defining my requirements to a large extent.

Comment: So what's preventing you from compiling it from source on a different (possibly personal) machine and then presenting that binary RPM? Sometimes nonsensical policies need to be worked around.

Answer (score 0):

[Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) can proxy FTP and satisfies all your requirements.

Comment: I had accepted this answer but I had to un-accept it when I found out how insanely limited Squid is as an FTP proxy - it won't pass on login credentials so it's useless for all but anonymous FTP.

Answer (score 0):

What about Proxy suite from Suse ?

I'm not sure if it still ships with opensuse, but it seems it was in 10.3.
See [this page on novell.com](http://www.novell.com/products/linuxpackages/opensuse/proxy-suite.html)
And [here](http://www.traceroot.fr/search.php?search=Proxy)(in french), you'll find recent patches, correcting bugs and enhancing log...

From the [src RPM](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/openSUSE:/Factory/standard/src/proxy-suite-1.9.2.4-173.9.src.rpm), I sure you'll be able to modify it to fit RHEL...

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/packages/ftpproxy/